# output results from nested loop in R

Tags: r, loops

In the attached data frame, I have 10 subjects (5 Male and 5 Female). Each subject has three analytes (A,B,C) and each analyte has three visit values (visit=1,2,3). Now I want to conduct two-group comparison Male vs Female by each analyte and each visit. I used nested loop with i in analyte and j in visit. The desired output format is attached (9 rows and 7 columns). I expect to have nine rows but only got three here. I think the output for i loop was not stored correctly, but I'm not sure how to include i correctly. Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

```
df1 = data.frame(id = c(1:10), gender = c(rep(c("F","M"),5)))
df2 = data.frame(id = c(1:10), analyte = c(rep(c("A","B","C"), 10)))
df3 = data.frame(id = rep((1:10),each=3), visit = rep(c("day1","day2","day3"),10))

set.seed(123)
df4 = data.frame(id = rep((1:10),each=9), val=rnorm(n = 90, mean = 0, sd = 1))
df5  = Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) merge(dtf1, dtf2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE), list(df1,df2,df3))
df  = cbind(df5,df4)[,-5]

mk1=unique(df$analyte)
mk2=unique(df$visit)

out=matrix(NA, ncol=7, nrow=9)

for(i in 1:length(mk1)){
  for (j in 1:length(mk2)){
    dd = df[as.character(df$analyte)==mk1[i]&as.character(df$visit)==mk2[j],]
    x = as.vector(dd$val[dd$gender=="F"])
    y = as.vector(dd$val[dd$gender=="M"])
    med1=as.numeric(quantile(x, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25), na.rm=TRUE, type=2)[3])
    med2=as.numeric(quantile(y, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25), na.rm=TRUE, type=2)[3])
    ci=wilcox.test(x, y, conf.int = TRUE, exact=FALSE)$conf.int
    out[j,] = c(mk1[i], mk2[j],length(x),length(y),
                med1, med2, wilcox.test(x, y, conf.int = TRUE, 
                                        exact=FALSE)$p.value)
  }
}

colnames(out)=c("Analyte", "VISIT", "Female (N)", "Male (N)",
                "Median of Female", "Median of Male", "P_wilxon")
```

[image: analytes table]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate issue is that you are re-assigning to same output matrix row. Below will only keep last three rows as *j* never reaches 9.

```
out[j,] <- ...
```

However, instead of nested `for` loops to iteratively assign outputs to a pre-defined matrix with dimensions hard-coded, use a more dynamic approach. Consider `by` to subset data frame by *visit* and *analyte* and then pass subsets into needed operation. At the end, row bind list of data frames for final object:

```
run_comparison <- function(dd) {
    x <- as.vector(dd$val[dd$gender=="F"])
    y <- as.vector(dd$val[dd$gender=="M"])

    med1 <- as.numeric(quantile(x, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25), na.rm=TRUE, type=2)[3])
    med2 <- as.numeric(quantile(y, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25), na.rm=TRUE, type=2)[3])

    wx <- wilcox.test(x, y, conf.int = TRUE, exact=FALSE)

    data.frame(ANALYTE = dd$analyte[[1]], Visit = dd$visit[[1]], 
               Female_N = length(x), Male_N = length(y),
               Female_Median = med1, Male_Median= med2, 
               P_Wilcox = wx$p.value)        
}

df_list <- by(df, df[c("analyte", "visit")], run_comparison)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: Hi Parfait, the function works very well and is much easier than a for loop. Thank you very much.